# JavaScript parse button value to post

Tags: javascript, html

i have a form that contains different buttons with different values that i want to post to a controller or something equal. Here is how this could look like:

```
<form action="thecontroller/post" method="post" id="buttons">
  <div class="select_direct">
      <button class="btn_quick_select" value="A">A</button>
      <button class="btn_quick_select" value="B">B</button>
      <button class="btn_quick_select" value="C">C</button>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="add">
</form>
```

So i want to submit the selected button (A, B or C) to the controller. As i want to satisfy the Open-Close-Principle, i want to be able to do this for any amount of buttons given, so my approach ist to parse the elements by class and filter for the active one:

```
var buttonValue;
function getSelectedButton() {
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("select_direct");
 buttons.foreach(function(button) { 
     if(button.isActive) { buttonValue = button.value; }
 });
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `isActive`? Also, `foreach` don't work, it's not a method of `HTMLCollection`s, nor is it capitalized properly even if it were

Comment: `buttons.$.each(function())` this will work for you

Comment: you are not selecting the buttons, your selector should be btn_quick_select not select_direct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So i want to submit the selected button (A, B or C) to the controller.

Sounds like you're re-inventing a radio button.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("buttons");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="letter"]:checked').value);
});
```

```html
<form action="thecontroller/post" method="post" id="buttons">
  <div class="select_direct">
      A<input type="radio" value="A" name="letter" />
      B<input type="radio" value="B" name="letter" />
      C<input type="radio" value="C" name="letter" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

So far what I understand form your question is that you want to `POST` the `value` of the `button` that is clicked. In this case you do not need a `submit` button. You can do it when a `button` is `clicked`. You can do it in following way:

```
$(".btn_quick_select").click(function(){
  var btnValue = $(this).val();
  //code to POST btnValue goes here...
});
```

Otherwise, if you want to `submit` then you can't do it using `button`. Use `checkbox` or `radio` instead. Then your markup will be look like this:

Let me konw if it is helpful for you.

```
<form action="thecontroller/post" method="post" id="buttons">
  <div class="select_direct">
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="value1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="value2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="value3">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="add">
</form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$("#buttons").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var btnValue = $(this).serialize();
  //code to POST btnValue goes here...
});
```

Hope it will be helpful. Let me know about it.

Comment: No, i want to submit the clicked value (A, B or C) when clicking the form submit. But asrottenoats stated this is a kind of re-invention of radio buttons:D

Answer (score 2):

No need for JavaScript.

If you want to first click on A/B/C and then the submit button, then don't use normal buttons for A/B/C, but radio buttons and use CSS to make them look like normal buttons.

If you want to just click on A/B/C and submit immediately, remove the normal submit button and just give A/B/C `type=submit`.